# Checking cyclic list of tuples in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm fairly new to Haskell and I'm trying to write a function that checks to see if the domino pieces are in a perfect cycle. The dominos are tuples of two items, and all are in one list. The condition is that the snd of a tuple must be equal to the fst of the next one, and also the fst of the first tuple and snd of the last one should be equal.
so for example:

```
[(2, 2)] -> true
[(5, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5)] -> true
[(5, 1), (2, 3), (3, 5)] -> false
```

Here's what I have so far (minimal reproducible version). I think the problem with it is that it doesn't check the first and last one with each other but I have no idea how I would go about solving it:

```
cycle [(x, y)] = x == y
cycle [(x, y), (a, b)] = and (y == a, x == b)
cycle (head:tail) = do
  let (headOfTail:restOfTail) = tail
  and (snd head == fst headOfTail, cycle (tail))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please don't call a custom function `cycle` (unless it's somehow an alternative to [the standard list-repeating function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle)).

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve a problem like this is to use the transitive property of dominoes to make a "virtual" domino.  For instance, we can start with a pattern match like so:

```hs
cycle ((a,b):(c,d):rest) = ...
```

At this point, if we know that `b` and `c` are equal, then we can pretend we have one big domino that starts with `a` on one side and has `d` on the other side.  If this new domino `(a,d)` works with the rest of our dominoes, then we should be good.

See if you can fill in the code!

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help! I think I solved it. Here's what I wrote: `cycle ((a,b):(c,d):rest) = do
    if b == c then 
      if a == snd (last rest) then True
      else False
    else False`

Comment: @AppleJuice That won't read the rest of the list: only the first two pairs and the last one are considered by your code. The answer above suggests to use recursion: after the check on the first two pairs, you can combine them into `(a,d)` and recurse, making the list shorter, until you have only one pair in the list.

Comment: @AppleJuice For a concrete example to demonstrate that flaw, `cycle [(5,2),(2,1),(3,5)]` will incorrectly be `True`.

Comment: @chi I wrote it as `domino_cycle ((a,b):(c,d):rest) = do
    if b == c then
      domino_cycle ((a,d):rest)
    else False` but it doesn't work, and I'm not really sure how else I would implement your solution

Comment: @AppleJuice Don't use `do` -- that's for monads and here you are not using one. The rest looks fine to me.